# Order network requests result with RxSwift

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I currently have a set of network requests to fire.
The problem is that I need to order the results of them to fit the order I fired them.

My current code is the following:

```
for url in config.fieldImages.map ({ URL(string: $0)! }) {
    self.getWheelFieldImage(url: url)
        .takeUntil(.inclusive, predicate: { (_) -> Bool in
            images.count == config.fieldImages.count - 1
        })
        .subscribe(onNext: { (anImage) in
            images.append(anImage)
        }, onError: { (error) in
            completion(nil, nil, error)
        }, onCompleted: {
            completion(images, false, nil)
            self.lastUpdate = Date()
        }, onDisposed: {
    })
    .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
}
```

**I'm wondering if there is an easy way to order these results in the same order I fired them, using RxSwift**.

EDIT:

I try to explain the problem better. I have this array with N URLs and I fire the requests one after the other (1,2,3,4...).

I need to have back the result from these requests in the same order (R1, R2, R3, R4, where R1 is the response from request 1 etc...) to store the images in the resulting array.

I can wait all to finish. No problem.

Comment: Do you need to fire them in specific order, or you need wait for all them complete and then have their results in same order as urls?

Comment: Updated question with more info :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without much changes in your original code you can achieve this by use using `enumerated()` on your urls list as:

```swift
/// Prefill your images with nil for each image
var images = Array<Int?>(repeating: nil, count: config.fieldImages.count)
for (index, url) in config.fieldImages.map ({ URL(string: $0)! }).enumerated() {
    self.getWheelFieldImage(url: url)
        .takeUntil(.inclusive, predicate: { (_) -> Bool in
            images.count == config.fieldImages.count - 1
        })
        .subscribe(onNext: { (anImage) in
            images[index] = anImage /// Store on proper position
        }, onError: { (error) in
            completion(nil, nil, error)
        }, onCompleted: {
            completion(images, false, nil)
            self.lastUpdate = Date()
        }, onDisposed: {
    })
    .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
}
```

Probably most RxWay will be use of `zip` operator as:

```swift
let streams = config.fieldImages
    .map { URL(string: $0)! }
    .map { self.getWheelFieldImage(url: $0) }
let images = Observable.zip(streams) // Observable<[UIImage]>
    .subscribe(
        onNext: { [weak self] images in
            completion(images, false, nil)
            self?.lastUpdate = Date()
        }, 
        onError: { error in
            completion(nil, nil, error)
        }
    )
    .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
```

You can read more about `zip` in [documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html)

Comment: Sorry, your solution seems interesting but I don't get how `images[index] = anImage` assure me that the position is right. I mean, when I fire the `self.getWheelFieldImage(url: url)` one after the other in the for-loop, I don't know which callback answers. It could be that I fire 1,2,3 and I have back 2,1,3. How the index assure me to store the right image in the right position?

Comment: @GrizzlyBear `enumerated()` convert sequence of items in sequence of indexes and items, so for each url we have his original index in array. This allow us to store result image on right position (which is same as index of url)

Comment: It seems to work! I didn't get 100% HOW, but it seems to work! Thanks! :)

Comment: @ManWithBear sorry I know this is a few years old, but could you explain how using zip ensures the order is maintained? Doesn't it just zip a URL to whichever result happened to come in next?

Comment: @tim_d you are right that `ReactiveX` doesn't specify order of elements inside of one `zip` event. `RxSwift` currently preserves order of [elements in zip event](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/main/RxSwift/Observables/Zip%2Barity.swift) but it's not mentioned in the docs.